# Context switching inside an object - referring to 'this' in a callback

Tags: javascript

So I have a class with a few methods, one of the methods is used as a callback. But depending on how I declare the callback, the pointer of `this` has a switched context. I'm wondering how to make this work where the pointer of `this` is the object itself.

An example of my issue:

```
return {
    init: function(){
        this.starting = 0;
        var _this = this;
        $.ajax({/* some params */})
        .done(function(response){
            _this.addOne(); // here the context is fine, one gets added
        })
        .fail( _this.subtractOne ); // the callback points to the function below, 
                                    // but 'this' doesn't point to the same thing
    },
    addOne: function(){
        this.starting++;
    },
    subtractOne: function(){
        this.starting--;
    }
}
```

How can I use the notation that `.fail` uses, but still subtract correctly?

Comment: Look into using the [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) method which lets you choose what `this` value you want to use in a function that you call.

Comment: You should just use the same syntax you've used for your done call i.e. `.fail(function () {_this.subtractOne();})`

Comment: @Stouffi, I understand which syntax works, this is just a contrived example to get at the issue I'm having.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `this` is determined by how the function is **called**, rather than how it's **written**.

jQuery calls its callback functions with `this` bound to whatever makes sense to jQuery at the moment (for example, for event handlers, `this` is bound to the DOM element that triggered the event).

Because of that, the `this` in `this.starting--` isn't what you think it is.

You can force `this` to be whatever you want by passing the result of `.bind()` on your function, like so:

```
.fail(_this.substractOne.bind(_this));
```

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 3):

`bind()` will make sure the call is made with a proper `this` reference:

```
.fail( _this.subtractOne.bind( _this ) );
```